# How to copy a single same same file in all active ips in LAN

Tags: networking

Please suggest me how to copy a single same file to all active IP addresses in LAN, same user and same passwords in all hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

hosts=( $(nmap -sP 192.168.6.0/20 | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+") )

for ip in "${hosts[@]}"; do
        rsync -a /location/to/file.txt user@"$ip":/where/to/put/
done
```

Here i have relied on `nmap` to check which hosts are up, the output can be wrong in some cases due to firewall issues. At first i have saved the active IP addresses in an array, then run over the array to get file copied to the hosts using `rsync` one by one.

You should use [key-based authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) for this otherwise it wil ask you password for each host, if you don't have key-based you can use some other UNSECURED and absolutely NOT RECOMMENDED methods like [`sshpass`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sshpass.1.html).

Comment: it will ask for one time password or have to type for all the ips

Comment: yes, i have mentioned that in the answer, you should use key-based authentication..i could show you this using `sshpass` but it is not recommended..

Comment: it will ask one time pasword , i have all same passwords?

Comment: If you use [key-based-authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys), then it will not ask for password, it will use keys..in `sshpass` you will have to provide the password as a plaintext..

Comment: no i dont have key auth

Comment: Please follow the link i have given and set up key-based-authentication....it will save you a lot of work..

Comment: without key based auth it wont work?

Comment: if i hve to scp to pnly linux machines coz have other OS also than linux , can u edit ur script as per my requirement please

Comment: It will work, just that you will be prompted for password for every host..if your number of active hosts is smaller you can simply use it as it is....or if you insist you can give the password as plaintext using `sshpass` command..

Comment: you can use `scp` instead of `rsync`..i have used `rsync` as it is popular because of its numerous options and delta transfer mechanism..

Comment: for each host  ihave to give the password?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22836/discussion-between-heemayl-and-khanthegeek).